# Join multiple triggers in one single trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've created three triggers for a table.

One trigger after the Insert, one after The Delete, an the last one after the Update.

My question is: Isn't there a way to join all these triggers on one single trigger ?

These are my three triggers :

**The AFTER INSERT Trigger :**

```
 DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER `augmenter_quantite_Article` AFTER INSERT ON `LigneInterventaire`
     FOR EACH ROW UPDATE Article 
         SET qteArt = qteArt + NEW.qteInv
       WHERE codeArt = NEW.codeArt
    //
    DELIMITER ;
```

**The AFTER DELETE Trigger :**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `diminuer_quantite_Article` AFTER DELETE ON `LigneInterventaire`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE Article 
     SET qteArt = qteArt - OLD.qteInv
   WHERE codeArt = OLD.codeArt
//
DELIMITER ;
```

**The AFTER UPDATE Trigger :**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `update_quantite_Article` AFTER UPDATE ON `LigneInterventaire`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     UPDATE Article
     SET qteArt = qteArt - OLD.qteInv 
     WHERE codeArt = OLD.codeArt;
     UPDATE Article
     SET qteArt = qteArt + NEW.qteInv
     WHERE codeArt = NEW.codeArt;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table” (from mysql documentation). Each trigger if defined for a specific event. You cannot create one trigger to be fired for different events.